# Expect a type specifier when Templated class instance used in another class as member variable

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have two classes A and B. A is template class and it has constructor with one integer argument. And another class B uses A's instance with int template argument. Now problem is that it says Type expected when I compile program.

Here is program.

```
template <typename T>
class A
{
public:
    A(std::size_t max_size)
    {

    }
};

class B
{
    A<int> list(100);
};
```

I am getting compilation problem in

```
A<int> list(100);
```

line.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use uniform-initialization `A<int> list{100}`, copy-initializaion `A<int> list = A<int>(100)` or direct initialization through the member initializer list: `B() : list(100) {}`. Data members can't be initialized the way you've done.

Comment: If feasible, setting max_size outside the ctor would also work.    A<int> list;  list.set_max_size(100);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the compiler parses the line

```
A<int> list(100);
```

it thinks you are trying to declare a function named `list` whose return type is `A<int>`. It tries to parse the contents within the parantheses to find the argument types, default values, etc. It expects to find a type but instead it finds a number

I'm guessing you meant to use:

```
 A<int> list[100];
```

which declares `list` to be an array of 100 `A<int>`s.

If you meant to use `100` as a parameter to the constructor of `A<int>`, you'll have to use:

```
class B
{
    B() : list(100) {}
    A<int> list;
};
```

Comment: I think he meant to use the constructor that takes an `std::size_t` parameter, not to create an array.

Answer (score 1):

change this

```
A<int> list(100);
```

to for example

```
A<int> list<int> li(100);
```

i-e provide a type (here I mentioned `int`)

Comment: That's not going to compile.